# How to make condition if sim card is absent then show dialog if not do something in android?

Tags: android

I have an app in which I have to check whether sim card is inserted in device or not and make some condition if sim is not inserted then show dialog else do something ,how can I do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below function returns true if sim is present.

```
 public static boolean isSimSupport(Context context) {
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);  //gets the current TelephonyManager
        return !(tm.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TelephonyManager API. this API provides access to information about the telephony services on the device.

for reference : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
int simState = manager.getSimState();
        switch (simState) {
            case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT:
                // do something
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED:
                // do something
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PIN_REQUIRED:
                // do something
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PUK_REQUIRED:
                // do something
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY:
                // do something
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN:
                // do something
                break;
        }
```